# Break ongoing loop started by a tkinter button

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, tkinter, break

I want to build a tkinter interface that can start doing some repetitive work when a "start" button is pressed, and break the ongoing loop when the "stop" button is pressed. However I noticed that the tkinter does not process any further job untill the ongoing loop is finished, (e.g. does not respond to the "stop" button click, does not update the textbox or label text as shown in the attached code). It seems to be related to the single thread nature of tkinter from what I read at stackoverflow. Can someone help with some specific code? I am new to tkinter/Python, I could not figure out a real solution although I read many general discussions on board.

```
import time
import Tkinter as Tk

def _start():
    for outer in range(5):
        if active_stat:
            time.sleep(1) # some code in the real app
        else:
            break
        for inner in range(5):
            if active_stat:
                #counterstr.set("%02d-%02d" % (outer,inner)) #does not update till the end of loop
                textbox.insert(Tk.END, "%02d-%02d\n" % (outer,inner)) #does not show till the end of loop
                print "%02d-%02d" % (outer,inner)
                time.sleep(1) #some code in the real app
            else:
                break

def _stop():
    active_stat=False

active_stat=True

root = Tk.Tk()

#counterstr=Tk.StringVar() 
#Tk.Label(root, textvariable=counterstr).pack(side=Tk.TOP)
textbox=Tk.Text(root) 
textbox.pack(side=Tk.TOP) 
Tk.Button(root, text='Start', command=_start).pack(side=Tk.LEFT)
Tk.Button(root, text='Stop', command=_stop).pack(side=Tk.LEFT)
Tk.Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).pack(side=Tk.LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I had to do something similar for work. I can post my solution using the `processing` module to run all my code in a separate process if you would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is, is that I would make your `active_stat` a tkinter variable, and then call its `get` method when ever you want to check if it:

EDIT: also, add `root.update()` to your loop. That should fix your problem. The reason for the tkinter variables is because of variable scope problems, which I initially though where your problem. (note: this code is for python 3...)

```
import time
import tkinter as Tk

def _start():
    for outer in range(5):
        if active_stat.get():
            time.sleep(1) # some code in the real app
        else:
            active_stat.set(True)
            break
        for inner in range(5):
            if active_stat.get():
                #counterstr.set("%02d-%02d" % (outer,inner)) #does not update till the end of loop
                textbox.insert(Tk.END, "%02d-%02d\n" % (outer,inner)) #does not show till the end of loop
                print ("{}-{}".format(outer,inner))
                time.sleep(1) #some code in the real app
            else:
                active_stat.set(True)
                break
            root.update()

def _stop():
    active_stat.set(False)


root = Tk.Tk()

active_stat = Tk.BooleanVar(root)
active_stat.set(True)

#counterstr=Tk.StringVar() 
#Tk.Label(root, textvariable=counterstr).pack(side=Tk.TOP)
textbox=Tk.Text(root) 
textbox.pack(side=Tk.TOP) 
Tk.Button(root, text='Start', command=_start).pack(side=Tk.LEFT)
Tk.Button(root, text='Stop', command=_stop).pack(side=Tk.LEFT)
Tk.Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).pack(side=Tk.LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your idea is good, but this won't work like this.  You have to create the BooleanVar AFTER you make the root window.  Otherwise, it blows up.

Comment: To The-IT and iCodez: Great! this is working as I wanted. Thank you very much.

Comment: To Eric Urban: Hi Eric, I would love to see how you do it with the processing module. Could you please post your solution? Thanks!